# Cast type in a generic method to a different one for inner generic method call

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I've got this repository method:

```
    public virtual T Get<T>(object primaryKey) where T : IDalRecord, new() //note: can't change the where clause
    {
        return Record<T>.FetchByID(primaryKey); // how? <--compile time error
    }
```

defined in a 3-rd party assembly:

```
    public class Record<T> where T : Record<T>, IRecordBase, new()
    {
        public static Record<T> FetchByID(object primaryKey) { /*...*/ }
    }
```

My `T` and the 3-rd party `T` are not directly compatible, however my objects that inherit from `Record<T>` also also implement `IDalRecord`, so i can cast the object instance to any of these type.

But how can i tell the compiler to **"cast" `(IDalRecord)T` to `(Record<T>)T`**?

Comment: Is the `void.` a typo? Is `FetchByID` supposed to be `static`?

Comment: yes, there was a type, and yes, FetchByID is static. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to tell the compiler that `T` actually inherits from `Record<T>`. The reason is simple: because it is not true, generally speaking. Indeed, your `Get` method may, theoretically, be called with any argument, not necessarily that inheriting from `Record<T>`.

The fact that `T` does, in fact, inherit from `Record<T>` only becomes known at runtime, when your method is actually called. Therefore, necessary checks and constructs must take place at that same moment.

```
interface IHelper { object Fetch(object key); }

class Helper<T> : IHelper where T : Record<T>, IRecordBase, new()
{
    public object Fetch(object key) { return Record<T>.FetchByID(key); }
}

public virtual T Get<T>(object primaryKey) where T : IDalRecord, new()
{
    var helperType = typeof( Helper<> ).MakeGenericType( typeof( T ) );
      // This will throw an exception if T does not satisfy Helper's where clause

    var helper = Activator.CreateInstance( helperType ) as IHelper; 
    return (T) helper.Fetch(primaryKey);
}
```

Keep in mind that is it entirely possible (and even encouraged) to cache those `Helper<T>` objects for performance.

You can also just use old dumb reflection: find the method FetchByID by name and call it dynamically. But that would cause enormous performance penalty.

Comment: @ScottRippey: Thank you, but, frankly, I don't see anything creative in it. To me, this looks like pretty much the only sane way.